# Median array index in an array of 5 values

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array of 5 numbers in Excel VBA.

Each array index number is an x coordinate and the array value at each index is the Y coordinate/value. I'm trying to find the "median" x coordinate in the array based on the y values within the array.

Example 1:

```
Array(1) = 1, Array(2) = 0, Array(3) = 1, Array(4) = 1, Array(5) = 2
```

I envisage the x coordinate median would be (after rounding) index 4 - are there functions in Excel would support determining this or perhaps some suggested code please?

Example 2:

```
Array(1) = 7, Array(2) = 1, Array(3) = 4, Array(4) = 7, Array(5) = 1
```

I envisage the x coordinate median would be (after rounding) index 3?

Example 3:

```
Array(1) = 1, Array(2) = 0, Array(3) = 0, Array(4) = 0, Array(5) = 6
```

I envisage the x coordinate median would be (after rounding) index 5?

Example 4:

```
Array(1) = 5, Array(2) = 0, Array(3) = 7, Array(4) = 0, Array(5) = 6
```

I envisage the x coordinate median would be (after rounding) index 3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share your attempts at coding this. There is always https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.median

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your definitions above are an accurate description, namely the x and y co ords.

Nonetheless, you are dealing with a 1 dimensional array and you are trying to find the median within it. As such, by the definition of a median, you need to reorganise your array in numerical order and find the number that divides the array in it's "upper" half and "lower" half. Once you establish this, you can either reference this number by it's orginal index value (x co ord by your definition), or it's new index value.

Let's go through your first example above for clarity.

Example 1 above:

```
Array(1) = 1, Array(2) = 0, Array(3) = 1, Array(4) = 1, Array(5) = 2
```

As such:

```
Array = Array(1, 0, 1, 1, 2)
```

Reordered:

```
Array(0, 1, 1, 1, 2)
```

As can be seen from above the only transformation that needs to occur is that the original index 1 and 2 need reordering to achieve this. If this is the route you have taken then index 3 (x co ord) will be your median index for the values within the array.

In closing, I think your median value will rely on a) the transformation you do from non-ordered to ordered, and b) the index value of the NEW array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer :)

I think I need to give some more information, the values I’m trying to find the “median” for - perhaps I should call it mid point - are risk ratings.

So the ratings are along the lines of:

Value at array index 1 = Insignificant 
Value at array index 2 = low
Value at array index 3 = medium
Value at array index 4 = high
Value at array index 5 = extreme

So if I have a range of opinions from different people about their view of risk I’d like to get a median or average risk value across the group.

Comment: So using example 1 I believe the risk rating is array index 4.

I’m not yet at the coding stage as I wanted to see what folks thought about how this could be achieved.

Thanks again for your help - I’m new to this!

Comment: @Tiberius1701a you mention you want to get the MEDIAN or AVERAGE. These are two different things. Perhaps you are referring to the MEAN of your array?

Comment: Hi Dean - I double checked the definition of MEAN and I don't think that's what I'm looking for. The value I'm looking for (avoiding using the word MEDIAN or AVERAGE) is the common risk value across all votes. Not to worry - and I really appreciate all feedback to date - I think I'll ponder this problem further and see if anything comes to mind. Thanks again.